# Passing javascript code in JSON

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

I am making an AJAX call with jQuery to a PHP script that needs to return javascript code embedded in a JSON result for the jQuery code to execute. How do I go about passing javascript code in JSON?

Comment: your ajax library should have JSON messaging support.

what are you using?

Comment: Are you sure you really need to pass code? In most circumstances, some prewritten functions in the initial JS payload combined with some data that describes which function to run with what arguments are a better bet.

Comment: I agree with David and Max S... Good question however.

Comment: Well, only the server knows what javascript code to execute, it doesn't yet exist in the client. That's why I need to know this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two ways:

1. You'll have to pass it as a string and use `eval()` on the client side.
2. You can use JSONP, and instead of doing a call, have your client side script insert a `<script>` with its `src` pointing to the server-side code that returns the new script.

In either case, make sure you secure it well - if the user can somehow insert their own code into your response, they could do some damage.

Comment: Is eval slower than just including the script the standard way? Of both of your suggestions, which is better and why?

Comment: JSONP would be marginally faster, and is used more often, but it's open to XSS attacks if you aren't careful. Myself, I wouldn't go with either and instead pass data that describes what I need to do to some existing function (see David's comment on your question).

Answer (score 0):

The definition of JSON doesn't allow for javascript functions to be transported. It is meant to be language independent. If you use a JSON parser rather than eval(), it will fail if the JSON contains any functions.

Douglas Crockford, who I believe coined the term [JSON](http://www.json.org) has a [JSON parser for javascript](http://www.json.org/json_parse.js)

Even JSONP doesn't return a function but a function call - `myFuncIAskedFor({ returned JSON })`
As others have mentioned, define your functions locally, it's the safest thing to do
Also use a JSON parser