# jQuery. How to execute script loaded from JSON?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, getscript

I have file like this:

```
{'html' : '<div id="bla">something</div>',
 'script' : ' $().ready(function() { /* some code */});' }
```

I need to load it with jQuery and execute the 'script' variable. I know about $.getScript, but I need to run the script not from URL, but from part of JSON file. Otherwise I would need to do 2 heavy requests to server instead of one (javascript code is not static).

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212478/passing-javascript-code-in-json

Comment: It looks like the json string is malformed. I just run it against: http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first [parse](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/):

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(jsonString);
```

Then prepare div for HTML:

```
<div id="forHtml">
</div>
```

And run your code:

```
$('#forHtml').html(obj.html);
eval(obj.script);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either use JavaScript's eval(script), or the jQuery.globalEval(script) if you need to:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.globalEval/