# How to run javascript based rules against a page?

Tags: javascript

I would like to run some rules against pages. These rules are essentially functions that check the page for information. They can be simple as in 'check if the page has a title tag' or more complex like 'check if all links on the pages are whitelisted based on example.com/allowed_links.json'. 
The rules would be run on the page on-demand only and come from a trusted source.

My first approach has been to create a rule service that sends back an javascript array of rules. All the client then has to do is go over the array and run each function in it. The response is a standard object {rule: [name], pass: [true|false], message: [some message about success/failure]}

Since this is on demand only, we fetch the rules from the service and run 'eval' on it.

**EDIT:** The response from 'mysite/rules' looks like this

```
RULESYSTEM.rules.push(function1() {...});
RULESYSTEM.rules.push(function2() {...});
...
```

```
    const RULESYSTEM = {
      rules: [],
    };
    let rules = fetch('mysite/rules')
    let rulesscript = await rules.text();
    eval(rulescript)
    ...
      //eval will  populate the previously declared rules array.
      let pass = true;
      for(let i=0; i < RULESYSTEM.rules.length; i++) {
        let rule = RULESYSTEM.rules[i];
        //This obj has only one property. Get that one.
        let result = rule();
        pass = pass && result.pass;
      }
    ...
```

This works perfectly fine. However it is receiving a lot of pushback as 'eval' is considered evil and to be avoided at any cost. The security is not an issue here since the source is within the organization itself and thus trusted.

Are there any other ways to implement a system like this.

Comment: You should define your rules and load the ones you need when you need then, not as strings you need to eval, but as a func you can immediately execute with whatever defined params

Comment: How do I load my rules when I need them? I have a chrome extension that fetches the rules and runs them against the page.

Comment: There are a lot of hacks you can do.  One of which is importing js files as needed and then running the contents.  You can query an endpoint which would build the JS file for you based on the items you need and then return it to the user as a Map and then iterate it.

Comment: My old job had a DB of js functions, and then would query that table for the javascript needed, and use whatever language in the backend to build a JS file which is returned to the user and then at runtime, they only see the js which was asked for, not leaking anything else, and then walking it and for each, executing it with whatever input you need.

Comment: @Fallenreaper that sounds a lot like what I am doing. Did you use eval to execute the js functions at runtime or are there other ways to do it?

Comment: i wasnt fetching them as strings.  I was on the fly creating a JS file and referencing it by the frontend application / injecting the javascript into the template.  Either way, it uses the server side tech to loop a over data and inject code prior to the front end referencing it

Answer (score 2):

It would appear that all you're attempting to do is to retrieve JSON data and transforming it into a javascript object.

```
fetch('mysite/rules')
.then(res=>res.json())
.then(data=>{
  //TODO: handle data which is your object/array
  console.log(data)
})
```

Thus no need for `eval`. Also you need to remember that `fetch` returns a promise and that `rules.text()` and `rules.json()` also returns a promise. The way you've currently written it won't work anyway.

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json)

> The json() method of the Body mixin takes a Response stream and reads it to completion. It returns a promise that resolves with the result of parsing the body text as JSON.

To answer your question:

> Is it possible to return javascript code as JSON

That's clearly a no, however there are alternatives ! You can simply fetch javacsript as text (as you've done) and programmatically create a script tag, load your javascript text in it and append it to your HTML file.

Or even better, you can simply dynamically create a script tag with the URL of your server endpoint sending javascript and append it to your HTML file.

Something like:

```
const script = document.createElement("script");
script.onload = function(){
  console.log("script loaded");
}
script.src = '/some/url/here';
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: The returned text is javascript that adds functions to the rules array declared earlier. Is it possible to return javascript code as JSON. Based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212478/passing-javascript-code-in-json it does not seem so.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to add this as an answer.  I will use some dummy data you can query based on an endpoint

```
Route("get-functions")
Response getJSFunctions(List<string> js_to_load){
  var options = getData();  //returns a list
  var guid = new Guid()
  var fp = File.open(guid.toString() + ".js", "w+")
  var out = "var fns = [" + options.join("\n") + "];";
  fp.write(out);
  fp.write(" var runner = options => fns.forEach(fn => fn(options) );");
  fp.close()
  return new Response({url: guid.toString() + ".js"})
}
```

Js:

```
$.json("get-functions", data => {
    let script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = data.url;
    document.head.appendChild(script)
    runner(options);
});
```

So what is happening is that you build a Temp JS FIle containing all JS Functions you want run, then add that file dynamically to the runtime.  Then you have a function which will always be available called runner, which you can immediately call.

Runner will iteratively call each function with a global list of options across the functions, which you can define on the clientside.

Instead of using C#, you can use any serverside or even Javascript if you are using node as your backend.  You need DB Access and file creation access on the host machine.  You will also want to delete the GUID files ocassionally as they are just one and done use files, so you can delete them all every 5 minutes or something.

I dont have the means right now to create a running sample.  I can create something a little later with Python if you like as the backend.